# using MySql.Data; not working with .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net

I load the reference MySql.Data and verify that this is loaded.

I place

```
using MySql.Data;
```

into my code, but it cannot find MySql.Data.

There are many versions of MySql.Data available and many solutions indicated for this in previous posts.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that the .NET Framework version is incompatible with the version of the MySql Connector/NET.

Check your version of the .NET Framework, since the Connector/NET only works up to .NET Framework 4.5.x and changing the version from 4.6 to 4.5.2 worked for me. (Project > Properties > Application > Target Framework).

REFERENCE: [MySQL Versions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html)